# Virtual function acting weird in inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Lemme explain my problem by giving an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class PC
{
public:
    PC():Data(0)
    {
    }
    virtual void display()
    {
        std::cout<<"The data is :"<<Data<<std::endl;
    }
protected:
    int Data;
};

class SmartPC:private PC
{
public:
    SmartPC():PC()
    {
    }
    void convert()
    {
        PC* temp=static_cast<PC*>(this);
        temp->display();
    }
    void display()
    {
        std::cout<<"The data is (in bb):"<<a<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SmartPC SmrtPC;
    PC* miniPC= static_cast<PC*>(&SmrtPC);
    SmrtPC.convert();
}
```

According to Scott Meyers : `static_cast<PC*>(this);` will create a temp base copy of SmartPC. But `temp->display();` executed the `display()` function of derived class. Why is that so? Shouldn't it execute the function of base's `display()`, since the object is now completely a copy of base of SmartPC?

Another question is that if I add the line `temp->data;` in `convert()` function , it says 
`PC::Data` is protected but I am accessing it from derived class scope i.e `SmartPC`, so why doesn't it work?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a citation for where Meyers said that? Perhaps you misunderstood him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to scott meyers : `static_cast<PC*>(this);` will create temp base copy of SmartPC. but `temp->display();` executed the `display()` function of derived class why is it so? it should execute function of base's `display()` , since the object is now completely a copy of base of SmartPC.

No copy is created, you are only casting *a pointer*.

Since the class is polymorphic, calling a `virtual` function via a pointer results in calling the "correct" version of the function (according to the *dynamic type* of the object, which is `SmartPC *`).

If, instead, `display` was not `virtual`, the version of the base class would have been called, since for non`virtual` methods it's the *static type* of the pointer to determine which version is to be called.

(`display` is `virtual` also in `SmartPC` even if it's not explicitly specified, the `virtual` qualifier is implied when overriding inherited `virtual` functions)

---

Notice instead that if you did:

```
PC temp(*this);
```

you would have actually created a *copy* of the current object, "sliced" to be an object of type `PC`. This is called "object slicing" and is performed by the copy constructor of `PC`; most often this is undesired behavior (because what was an object of the derived class actually becomes an object of the base class, and polymorphism do not work as some may expect).

---

> Another question is that if i add the line `temp->data;` in `convert()` function , it says `PC::Data` is protected but i am accessing it from derived class scope i.e `SmartPC`, so why doesn't it works?

Conceptually, when you try to access `temp->data` you're trying to access a `private` member of another object (it's not important that `temp` is actually `this`), so the access is denied. Your "derived class privileges" to access `protected` members work only on `this`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a copy of the class, it is a reference to the base class object, and as such, it behaves polymorphically like any other.

The reason you can't access the protected members is because you used private inheritance.

Comment: Can you explain this **The reason you can't access the protected members is because you used private inheritance** . Since derived class can access its protected member whether inheritance is private or public inside the scope of class. Thanks